# JDK11 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, oracle

Window user. I am new to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on top of Virtual Toolbox. I have questions/problems wrt installing JDK 11. The Ubuntu is clean slate. Nothing is installed on this OS. From what I understand, starting Java11, there is no different between Oracle's Java releases and openJava releases. I am installing JDK 11 from Oracle.
I followed the step-by-step guide in: https://websiteforstudents.com/install-oracle-java-jre-jdk-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-beta/ (please note the install steps are for JDK 9 not 11, but the comments from viewers said they had no problem using the same steps to install JDK 11) 
I ran into a problem & a few questions (these install steps are so different than those in Windows).

Question:

From the above link, near the top middle, the author shown how to install java, javac and javaws. E.g.:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-9.0.4/bin/javaws" 1010
```

What does 1010 means?

Problem:

I had no problem running the update-alternatives --install commands for (JDK11) java, javac. But when I tried to install javaws, I ran into problem.

The command I used:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/bin/javaws" 1010
```

The error returned:

```
sudo update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/bin/javaws doesn't exist
```

I had no problem using similar commands from the above URL to install java, javac. But javaws threw an error.

Can someone kindly suggest what to do to resolve this issue for javaws install?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. 1010 means priority, alternatives with bigger priority value will be chosen in auto mode.  Since you only have one Java version installed, it is not important.
2. The error returned is very clear, javaws just doesn't exist. Java Web Start is removed from Java SE 11. Developers will need to transition to other deployment technologies.